# How to stop Jenkins from listing all TFS workspaces

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I'm new to Jenkins. I'm using Jenkins 2.5. I'm using the TFS plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) 4.1.0. Whenever I run a job that gets latest from TFS, TFS first lists every workspace which is a problem because I work for a large company - it lists 5,000 workspaces. This page https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/pull/65/commits seems to indicate that a ShowWorkspaces flag was added, but I can't find it anywhere. Maybe this was never added. Does anyone have a way to get Jenkins to stop listing all TFS workspaces?

Answer (score 2):

It's [a known issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30330) for now. And seem to be fixed until version 4.2.0

> I'll most likely include a fix for this defect in version 4.2; I'll
>   update this issue once it's released.
>   *Olivier Dagenais*

Moreover, this flag was added successful https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/pull/65/commits/d56346c4b3989a3edaed547ae55ed39233743be8 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you care about this getting fixed, please vote for it at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30330.